# Page Hits Counter for Multiple Webpages

Tags: php

I don't know where to begin and need some guidance...

Looking for a simple **page hits counter** for a directory website. Each page of the directory (100+ pages) will have its own publicly-viewed page counter. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit diffuse as it is now. It is not clear from your question whether you are searching for an existing hit counter solution (and possibly help on how to implement that on your site) or whether you want to code your own solution.

In either case you should try to get some things sorted out before you start:

1. What are the requirements for the hit counter? Or to put it differently: What features should it offer?

   - Should it just count the overall hits of every page or should it provide a finer resolution, e.g. showing the hits per day?
   - Should it provide an option to not show or not count hits on some special pages?
   - etc.
2. Hit counters usually use some kind of database to store the hit counts for the various pages. What kinds of databases are available on your server that could be used for that purpose?

If these questions are answered, you could either look for an existing solution that meets your requirements or start working on your own implementation. It is usually easier to work towards achieving some end, if you have a clear goal in mind. (Maybe you already have that, but then the question does not show it.)